# SQL Server: FullText index initial population performance

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am adding a fulltext index on a varbinary(max) filestream column (table with 2,100,538 rows).

The index has been in 'Full Population In Progress' status since 2021-05-12 8AM (4.5 days) with 69,265 itemcount. The server is running <5% cpu. Is there some way to speed up population of the index?

[Extension, Count, Avg size in kb breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkUOU.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You don't tell us which filters you have installed. As the CPU is pretty low, it suggests you are RAM or I/O bound.